# Two if conditions Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to validate input in this VB program that calculates football stats. If both boxes are empty when a user clicks Update Stats, it should display a message box. However, with this code it shows the message whether both boxes are empty or if they have values entered. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
  'validate user input (ensure textBoxes aren't blank)
  If passYdTextBox.Text = "" And rushYdTextBox.Text = "" Then

     MessageBox.Show("Please enter values into pass yards box or rush yards box")

  End If
```

Comment: Is it possible that they contain spaces or other invisible characterS? Try calling `Trim()` on the Text property, or check using `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()`.

Comment: The user is supposed to enter numeric values in the textbox, which is then converted to a string. I don't know if that is causing a problem or not.

Comment: That should not be any problem. Just wondering, do you need the entered value as a string or as an integer?

Comment: @SimonJensen the entered value would be an integer, then it is converted to string, so it can be output into a label

Comment: Anything typed in a text box is from the start a string no matter if you type in "123" or "hello". Can you do me a faver, put a breakpoint at the line where your if starts, then point at `passYdTextBox` and `rushYdTextBox`, there should appear a little info on both with a comment saying `{text = ""}`. Could you tell me what is inside the quotations of both?

Comment: If I did what you said correctly, it just shows a box stating "FriendsWithEvents passYdTextbox As System.Windows.Forms.Textbox"

Comment: Also tried String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace and it still displays the messagebox when it is not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to check this would be to use the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method or even doing something like `passYdTextBox.Text.Length > 0`  as your problem could be due to data types and casting.

I'm sure you have already considered this as well, but this validation alone is not enough to avoid an exception. You will also need to ensure that the Text in the field is numeric before trying to cast the String.

Comment: Thanks @Andy When I used the .length < 0 property, it will allow me to enter a value into one box without the message prompt. but if i try to leave both blank, it does nothing at all.

Comment: This is because both conditions must be satisfied for the statement to execute, I believe you need to use `Or` instead of `And`. This way the only way you won't see the message box is if both text fields have something in them.

Comment: I would like the message to appear only if both textboxes are left empty with no user input

Comment: Just to clarify before we go any further, your if condition should be `passYdTextBox.Text.Length < 1 And rushYdTextBox.Text.Length < 1`. I've just realised I didn't really make that too clear. Let me know how it goes because I'm not sure I can help any further without more code

Comment: That is correct. Basically, I would like a messagebox to appear only if the user leaves both boxes blank. If they type in passing yards, rushing yards, or both, then it should not bring up the message box.

Comment: Then the condition I gave you in my previous comment should work as both conditions, that check the text box is empty, must be true for the if statement to execute. Have you tried it? If so, what exactly is the problem now?